# Accent mark not showing in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, diacritics, ng-view

I'm working in Eclipse with a Dynamic Web Project and I have some problems with accent marks. Using AngularJS, in the main html page accent marks and 'ñ' are shown but there I have a ng-view and when display in Chrome doesn't show accent marks there!

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" ng-app="agriweaapp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>AgroWea</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body ng-controller="mainAppController as vm">
    <p>Works here: á ñ</p>
    <div class="container" ng-view></div>

    <!-- Modules -->
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My main.html that goes in ng-view:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Ahorra con AgriWea</h1>
    <p>Gracias a nuestro sistema de recomendación de riego podrás ahorrar con más eficiencia. Esto es posible a nuestro sistema basado en predicciones meteorológicas y ¡los datos de tus cultivos!</p>
</div>
```

My app.js:

```
angular.module('agriweaapp', ["ngRoute"])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            controller: "mainAppController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            templateUrl: "pages/main.html",
            resolve: {
                  delay: function($q, $timeout) {
                    var delay = $q.defer();
                    $timeout(delay.resolve, 100);
                    return delay.promise;
                  }
            }
        });
})
.controller("mainAppController", function() {
    var vm = this;
})
```

My html files preferences:

[Eclipse HTML file preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ5na.jpg)

Result:

[Chrome view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvHgL.jpg)

Comment: You have a problem with character encoding somewhere. First of all go check that you saved all your HTML documents in the same encoding (should normally be UTF-8.)

Comment: @CBroe I've added my HTML file preferences in Eclipse, is UTF-8.

Comment: Does your server return the correct charset in the Content-Type header (if any) for these resources?

Comment: The response header says "Content-Type:text/html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the same code in my workspace. Utf Encoding does not inherit to templates in ng-view. I fixed the issue using below code in ng-view templates (main.html in your case)

`<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
<head>`

Then it works perfectly fine.

Cheers

Comment: I wasn't sure if that was correct, but I'll do it 'cause it fix my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could fix all my accent issue when using Eclipse changing the Preferences (Windows->Preferences->General->Content Type) which were setup with a CP1252. After these change (I replaced all CP1252), the nightmare endedup.
The Default encoding box is on the right bottom dialog box.